# Migrating from Atlassian Subversion to Assembla

Tags: svn, jira, assembla

With Atlassian discontinuing its hosted Subversion repositories, I have migrated to Assembla's hosted SVN.  Our Jira installation (also cloud based, at Atlassian) still generates automatic links to atlassian SVN when it sees revision tags such as r1501 in the ticket comments.

I would like to reconfigure such that those links point to Assembla rather than Atlassian.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that there is no direct integration available from Assembla to Jira on-demand. Assembla has their own ticket-management system.  Oh well!